# Set defaul value for DVWP parameters programmatically

Tags: javascript, data-view-web-part, default-value

Good day

I need to set default value for ParameterBinding of DVWP as follows:

```
<ParameterBinding Name="StartDate" Location="Postback;Connection;" DefaultValue="2012-07-01T00:00:00Z"/>
<ParameterBinding Name="EndDate" Location="Postback;Connection;" DefaultValue="2012-09-30T00:00:00Z"/>
```

I want this default value change programmatically depending on quarter of the year.
I use javascript function on page load where i get first and last day of the Quarter. But i have no idea how to send these parameters to DVWP not using Query variable

When I use `__doPostBack(WP, <parameters>)` the page reloads endless :))) 
Can ECMAscript object model access these parameters and change it?

Do you have any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: Lena, can you use Query string parameters to send the required default dates in URL ?

Comment: well, i'm not sure, i'd like to use just like postback parameter. How to use as query string parameters via javascript?

Comment: Yes, via javascript you can send parameters as Query String and then use those parameters in Binding...

Comment: You can have a look [here](http://arsalkhatri.wordpress.com/2012/01/07/external-list-with-bcs-search-filters-finders/), I have used Content Editor Web Part to take input the text parameters and send them as Query String and filter the XSLTListViewWebPart... You can skip the external list part...

Comment: Thanx, I see) Frankly speaking, when you suggested me to use QueryString, I've already done some Ecmascripts (where i get webpart ID) and  _doPostBack for applying filters. I didn't want filter parameters show up in URL string. But now I decided to do like you, i used Query String Filter after  window.location.href..... Thak you for idea )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lena,

Can you use Query string parameters to send the required default dates in URL ?

If yes, You can have a look [here](http://arsalkhatri.wordpress.com/2012/01/07/external-list-with-bcs-search-filters-finders/), I have used Content Editor Web Part to take input the text parameters and send them as Query String and filter the XSLTListViewWebPart... You can skip the external list part...

Comment: Oh!! So many thanks! even if it doesn't make sence for your reputation))) ha-ha)))) :P

Comment: hehe, you are most welcome.. if we were sharing the location, I might have asked you for a dinner or lunch.. but since we are living in different countries - marking as answer will serve the purpose :P

Comment: @Arsalan - please stop using signatures, see http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures

Comment: @Ryan, okay I won't be using from now onwards! :)